# Dynamic field and operator in MongoEngine query

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-wtforms, flask-mongoengine

I have a application where users should be able to build complex search queries.The problem is that when I'm building a query with the `Q` object I can't find a way to make the parameters dynamic.

```
Users.objects.filter(age__gte=18)
```

Given the query above, I would want to make `age` and `gte` dynamic. I get them in `str` format from a HTML form, but how can I translate them into a real parameter? I want something along the lines of this:

```
Users.objects.filter('{}__{}=18'.format(field, operator))
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that python can take as parameters `list` `*args` and `dict` `**kwargs` of parameters. So for your case:

```
Users.objects.filter(**{'{}__{}'.format(field, operator): 18})
```